Passing yet-unknown types to instances of generic class objects
I've got a generic class:

export class EdocReport<TtypeDTO, TTypeFinalObject> {
  constructor(
    private _address: string,
    private _queryKey: QueryKey,
    private _sort: "NONE" | keyof TtypeDTO | ((dataArray: TtypeDTO) => TtypeDTO)
  ) {
    this._address = _address;
    this._queryKey = _queryKey;
    this._sort = _sort;
  }

//logic to convert/map from type TtypeDTO into TTypeFinalObject

}

I want to use object instances of that class in custom hook that will look like:
export const useGetEdocReports = (edocReportsData: TEdocReportsData) => {
//fetching data / sorting / mapping ... whatever 
}

The incoming argument data type is to be:
type TEdocReportsData = {
  token: string;
  setIsLoading: (boolValue: boolean) => void;
  reports: EdocReport[];
};

Here the problem occurs. I want to pass an array of reports (instances of EdocReport class), all of them will have different pairs of DTO type and finalObject type, but TypeScript reports that:
Generic type 'EdocReport<TtypeDTO, TTypeFinalObject>' requires 2 type argument(s).

As if I would have to make declaration in advance and specify what the type TtypeDTO and TTypeFinalObject will be.
I wish to finally use the hook like this:
useGetEdocReports({
  token: "token",
  setIsLoading: (boolValue: boolean) => setIsCustomLoading(boolValue),
  reports: [
    new EdocReport<DTOtype1, Type1>({...required_data}),
    new EdocReport<DTOtype2, Type2>({...required_data2}),
    new EdocReport<DTOtype3, Type3>({...required_data3})
  ]
})


Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without having to deal with problems you're not asking about. Any undeclared types or values should be either declared, replaced with things that are declared, or removed. Right now we have a bunch of errors and it makes it hard to get started in a way that allows us to test our ideas. Also, TTypeFinalObject is currently unused; either remove that or use it in the example, please. A [mre] can be a toy example, it doesn't have to be an excerpt of your actual code.

Just feed your type with <any, any>.
You could also use const so TS could infer exact types provided in the report array if needed for some usage.
Playground
export class EdocReport<TtypeDTO, TTypeFinalObject> {
}

export const useGetEdocReports = <const D extends TEdocReportsData>(edocReportsData: D) => {
    return edocReportsData;
}

type TEdocReportsData = {
  token: string;
  setIsLoading: (boolValue: boolean) => void;
  reports: EdocReport<any, any>[]
}

const reports = useGetEdocReports({
  token: "token",
  setIsLoading: (boolValue: boolean) => setIsCustomLoading(boolValue),
  reports: [
    new EdocReport<Number, Date>(),
    new EdocReport<Date, string>(),
    new EdocReport<number, boolean>()
  ]
})

/*
const reports: {
    readonly token: "token";
    readonly setIsLoading: (boolValue: boolean) => any;
    readonly reports: [EdocReport<Number, Date>, EdocReport<Date, string>, EdocReport<...>];
}
*/


Using any is certainly the most expedient way to proceed, but I can't tell if that actually satisfies the OP here without more info about what their code looks like (depending on use case, any might allow things that are actually invalid).  I didn't downvote, by the way.

@jcalz the report type doesnt have narrowed generic params ‍♂️ which is strange

Thank you!
<any, any> did the trick for now. I will surely constrain the  in time.
I was stucked .. .now I can go further :), thank you again for your time and will to help.

Done. Thank you Alexander.
